# Universal links - Error no apps with domain entitlements

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have followed all the instructions on this website https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

and upload it to the server, and without .json just a file with name apple-app-site-association and I can even access my own AASA in here
https://www.tribeapp.com.sg/apple-app-site-association

but the problem is I cannot open my app through the link and when I check it in apple validator it's showing this description below

> Error no apps with domain entitlements The entitlement data used to
>   verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released
>   version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

I have asked some of the people but they said that I have to wait 48 hours as it said, is it true?

Comment: I have checked links mentioned by you but it seems tedious as I dun know much more about that process but I recommend you to use http://www.branch.io to implement deep link.

Comment: i have tried branch.io before, but i can not find the way how to implement universal links. i mean i cannot set the scheme to be https, because i need to set the link domain like this "https:// www.tribeapp.com.sg" to direct user to my app

Comment: Branch covers Universal Links. You just need to provide your bundle identifier and your Apple App Prefix.

Comment: but branch domain is limited right? i mean you can not set the domain to be like this "https:// tribeapp.com.sg";, because i don't know how to set it like that –

Comment: I am having the same issue, and I still did not get it to work. I noticed in your link, that the content-type header is not application/json. You can see that others like booking.com are using application/json headers. Not sure if that can help...

Comment: @AngelGarcíaOlloqui mine has works already, it will works if you hold the link that you receive from email or write in note. if it works, there will be a menu to open from your app

Comment: I ran into the same issue. the universal link works on some devices but not all of them. using the apple tool got the same error no apps with domain entitlements. my app is up for > 48 hrs. Has anybody figured out what the root cause is?

Comment: have the same issue. no solutions yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. What I know so far has fixed this for others (from different sources on the internet and apple's docs) -
The apple-app-site-association file
- needs to be at either root level or under /.well-known/
- not have a .json extension
- should not have redirects (use a sniffing tool like Charles to check this) 
- have the content type set to application/json.

Also check your entitlements file and provisioning profile as mentioned here - [Apple association file fetched in development but not in TestFlight and App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735578/apple-association-file-fetched-in-development-but-not-in-testflight-and-app-stor)

Unfortunately, I've checked all of this and still haven't found the issue. Hoping the info above fixes it for someone else.