# Apple association file fetched in development but not in TestFlight and App Store

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight, ios-provisioning, ios-universal-links

Universal links work perfectly fine in development, but once I sign the applications and deploy them to TestFlight and App Store, it looks like the apple-app-site-association is not fetched and therefore the app isn't registered for oppening the universal links.

**1.     /.well-known/apple-app-site-association** file:

```js
{  
  "applinks": {  
  "apps": [],  
  "details": [{  
  "appID": "myteamid.com.mycompany.appName",  
  "paths": ["*"]  
  }]  
  }  
}
```

The server part looks OK, since it is successfuly fetched whenever I run the app via the cable on my phone.

App Search API Validation tool returns this for Link to application:

Action required

- Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how
  to implement the recommended Universal Links.
- Error no apps with domain entitlements
- The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app. This data may take 48 hours to update.

**2) Capabilities:**

Associated domains - ON with Domain list of:
applinks: link.mycompany.com

Other things I have turned on are: Push Notifications and Background Modes.

**3) Provisioning profile:**
I created a new one after adding the Universal links and Push notifications and it includes:

**Capabilities:**

- Associated Domains,
- List item
- Game Center,
- In-App Purchase,
- Keychain Sharing,
- Push Notifications.

Entitlements:

- get-task-allow,
- app-enviroment,
- com.apple.developer.associated-domains,
- com.apple.developer.team-identifier,
- application-identifier,
- beta-reports-active,
- keychain-access-groups

**4) While installing the app,** it behaves different in test flight then it does when loading via cable:

- **Via cable** I can see the successfull http request for the apple-app-site-association file and finally form the process swcd: **"Added service 'applinks', appID 'myteamid.com.mycompany.appName', domain 'link.mycompany.com' "**
- **Test flight** - when installing there is no sign of http request and the following line is shown if I previously had the app installed via cable: **"Removed service 'applinks', app ID 'myteamid.com.mycompany.appName', domain 'link.mycompany.com' (removed domain) "**

This of course results in the fact that whenever I install the app via TestFlight or Describution, the Universal links do not work.

Any ideas where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got to the bottom of this with help of Apple Developer Technical Support. In my (cordova) project folder there are two files:

Entitlements-Debug.plist
Entitlements-Release.plist

When I add the value applinks:mywebpage.com to Capabilities->Associated domains->Domains, the Entitlements-Debug.plist got the lines:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
  <string>applinks:mywebpage.com</string>=
</array>
```

BUT the Entitlements-Release.plist did not change. What I did to solve the issue is to copy-paste the generated lines form the Entitlements-Debug.plist. After this, I did the exact same Archive and upload process as before and everything worked fine.

Comment: thanks a lot, and just follow up this file is under platform/ios/project-name/ folder

Comment: I know it's usually not advised to add a "Thank you" comment, but I want you to thank you anyway for, even being a new user, spending the time to come back here after two weeks to answer your own question. Thanks!